# What word is he saying in «I want to read you a couple of things will use as a (...)»?

Tags: vocabulary

I'm listening to [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-wWBGo6a2w&list=PL22J3VaeABQD_IZs7y60I3lUrrFTzkpat&index=1&ab_channel=JordanBPeterson), and at the mark of 1h50m50s approx., the lecturer says the following:

> I want to read you a couple of things we'll use as a (...)

(...) is a placeholder for what sounds to me as 'progerom', a word which I cannot find anywhere -- except as a name of a company, which I doubt it's what he intended to say.

What is what he said, and what is its meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to read you a couple of things will use as a (...)

**Note** "will" should be "we'll, meaning "we will".

The missing word is **prodroma** and, if you switch on subtitles you'll see this. It's unusual  for Jordan Peterson to make mistakes, but I think the word should have been "prodromus".

> **prodroma** A symptom or sign that is characteristic or premonitory of the onset of a disease https://www.lexico.com/definition/prodroma

> **prodromus** A book or treatise which is introductory or preliminary to another, usually larger, work. https://www.lexico.com/definition/prodromus

Comment: Many thanks for the answer! I don't think I would ever have got there without your help. ;)

Comment: also, thanks for pointing out the typo ;)